# How to fix mismatch processor architecture, unexpected e_machine, due to a .so file

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin android project and am currently using Visual Studio 2015.

Inside of my **MainActivity.cs**, I have the following code:

```
Com.Alk.Sdk.SharedLibraryLoader.LoadLibrary("alksdk", this);
```

which then goes into:

```
// Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.alk.sdk']/class[@name='SharedLibraryLoader']/method[@name='loadLibrary' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String'] and parameter[2][@type='android.content.Context']]"
        [Register ("loadLibrary", "(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;)Z", "")]
        public static unsafe bool LoadLibrary (string p0, global::Android.Content.Context p1)
        {
            if (id_loadLibrary_Ljava_lang_String_Landroid_content_Context_ == IntPtr.Zero)
                id_loadLibrary_Ljava_lang_String_Landroid_content_Context_ = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID (class_ref, "loadLibrary", "(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;)Z");
            IntPtr native_p0 = JNIEnv.NewString (p0);
            try {
                JValue* __args = stackalloc JValue [2];
                __args [0] = new JValue (native_p0);
                __args [1] = new JValue (p1);
                bool __ret = JNIEnv.CallStaticBooleanMethod  (class_ref, id_loadLibrary_Ljava_lang_String_Landroid_content_Context_, __args);
                return __ret;
            } finally {
                JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef (native_p0);
            }
        }
```

The problem I am having is that when it calls the *JNIEnv.CallStaticBooleanMethod*, it throws this exception:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.pai.rp/app_lib/libalksdk.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3
--- End of managed Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError stack trace ---
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.pai.rp/app_lib/libalksdk.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:908)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1542)
at com.alk.sdk.SharedLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(SharedLibraryLoader.java:44)
at com.pai.rp.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at com.pai.rp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6973)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

From what I've been able to research I've found that

- e_machine: 3 indicates the expected arch is Intel 80386 ([ELF Headers](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2000-07-17/ch4.eheader.html)).
- When using a Google Nexus 10 emulator it seems to work, however when
  I use the Galaxy Tab E (ARM) through USB debugging, it crashes and gives me
  this error.

So the question is, how do I correct this?

Comment: What 3rd-party library is that?

Comment: @SushiHangover, I'm using a Alks Copilot as a 3rd party navigation system. I get their jar file and created a Bindings Library with it

Comment: I would imagine ALK has different jars for different ARCH types. If you unpack that the jar you have, does it have multiple .so arch within it?

Comment: @SushiHangover no actually, I used a Java Decompiler and all it shows me are two classes. AlkMsg.Class and SharedLibraryLoader.Class